# Structured programming in visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, structure

This might be a rather big question to just answer shortly; much kudos for someone wanting to explain. References to book/other websites/youtube links/something else nice would be fine.

I am getting the hang of programming in C# using visual studio. And my programs are getting bigger and complexer. I'm trying very hard to keep it structured but every time again I find myself ending up messing it up. Functions, variables, guievents and everything in the same form. Finally, I cant find anything without the ctrl+f function anymore.

The variables which are used on multiple forms are stored on a seperate form, which creates more overview. Static values are defined at the top of my program and used in for example switch/case statements.

But still; its very easy to mess up everything. I want more structure in my programs, but I do not really have an example of good structured programming. I do not really know what is standard to keep in the main form, or what should go in seperate forms. Any information on this topic is welcome:)

Comment: [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses) has a 30 day free trial, I would recommend it.

Comment: You've a lot of statics? Because in this case you should teach yourself more software-design basics.

Comment: I am currently making a program which interfaces with a custom device, I declared all commands which could be sent to the device as static

Comment: Don't confuse structured programming as you use the term with *structured programming*, an approach to software development developed from the late 60s by such luminaries as Hoare, Dijkstra and Dahl. You don't appear to be making the mistake of confusing the two, but Googling the term 'structured programming' might not provide the right sort of help.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark what should I google instead to get the result i am looking for? I am looking for examples how I should design a program which I can maintenace and keep expanding

Comment: Oh I dunno, *design patterns* is a popular topic, *software architecture* another, but you might be better off finding an open-source program in the same domain as your own and doing some reverse engineering from code to design.  And definitely take @JamieKeeling's advice and dig out a copy of *Code Complete*.  It might not answer the questions you are currently asking, but it answers a lot of questions you should be asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you purchase a copy of [Code Complete by Steve McConnell](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1350893502&sr=8-1).

Snippet from the Amazon page:

- Design for minimum complexity and maximum creativity
- Reap the benefits of collaborative development
- Apply defensive programming techniques to reduce and flush out errors
- Exploit opportunities to refactor—or evolve—code, and do it safely
- Use construction practices that are right-weight for your project
- Debug problems quickly and effectively
- Resolve critical construction issues early and correctly
- Build quality into the beginning, middle, and end of your project

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to get a copy of this book!

Comment: Great book but very 'heavy' if you're beginner.

Comment: I found a digital copy online; I'll read that, and purchase the book if I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

For Variables shared across multiple forms, why not put them in a single CS file and reference them? This centralises them into a single place and makes them easier to maintain.

It would be best practice to put your business and database access logic into separate CS files and use them in such a way that your Form accesses your business layer, and your business layer accesses your database layer.

You can structure your application any way you like. Where a CS file resides (as in its containing folder) does not affect your code. Visual Studio will automatically set the namespace to match the folder it is in but you can override this.

Answer (score 0):

You may also benefit from making your code more object-oriented, which will wrap related code up into separate classes in their own .cs files. To get you started, you say you are interfacing to a custom device. Have you got a class that represents this device? Look at the names of the variables and methods in your code - do they contain nouns? If so, consider making them into classes too. Where you use verbs, then this suggest methods to add to the class.

So, if you have a method called InitialiseDevice, then this suggests a class called Device, that has an Initialise method.

Obviously there is a lot more to object-oriented programming, and a lot of books on it - you may like this: [Beginning C# Object-Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235306).

Comment: Thanks! I'll was indeed planning on creating seperate classes for each device type. I'll check out the link and continue learning!